# error 10009 when refunding an authorized transaction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a paypal transaction which is authorized then captured. I want to refund it using .net code of `refundtransaction` I have the following error:
`You can not refund this type of transaction`

```
Public Function RefundTransactionCode(ByVal refundType__1 As String, ByVal transactionId As String, ByVal amount As String, ByVal note As String, ByRef resp As RefundTransactionResponseType) As AckCodeType
        Dim caller As New CallerServices()

        Dim profile As IAPIProfile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile()
        '
        '            WARNING: Do not embed plaintext credentials in your application code.
        '            Doing so is insecure and against best practices.
        '            Your API credentials must be handled securely. Please consider
        '            encrypting them for use in any production environment, and ensure
        '            that only authorized individuals may view or modify them.
        '            


        ' Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
        profile.APIUsername = AppSettings("APIUsername")
        profile.APIPassword = AppSettings("APIPassword")
        profile.APISignature = AppSettings("APISignature")
        profile.Environment = AppSettings("Environment")
        caller.APIProfile = profile
        ' Create the request object.
        Dim concreteRequest As New RefundTransactionRequestType()
        concreteRequest.Version = "51.0"

        ' Add request-specific fields to the request.
        ' If (amount IsNot Nothing AndAlso amount.Length > 0) AndAlso (refundType__1.Equals("Partial")) Then

        Dim amtType As New BasicAmountType()
        amtType.Value = amount
        amtType.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.CAD
        concreteRequest.Amount = amtType
        concreteRequest.RefundType = RefundType.Full
        ' Else
        'MsgBox(0)
        'concreteRequest.RefundType = RefundType.Full
        ' End If
        concreteRequest.RefundTypeSpecified = True
        concreteRequest.TransactionID = transactionId
        concreteRequest.Memo = note

        ' Execute the API operation and obtain the response.
        '   Dim pp_response As New RefundTransactionResponseType()
        resp = DirectCast(caller.[Call]("RefundTransaction", concreteRequest), RefundTransactionResponseType)
        Return resp.Ack

    End Function
```

Comment: This is not a coding error, but more something to do with the transaction. I would suggest contacting PayPal Merchant Technical Services at https://www.paypal.com/mts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise finding the transaction in your PayPal account and looking at it. It is probably an Authorization, Order, Pending transaction, or some other type of transaction.

**You can only refund a capture/sale, that was sent to the account you are sending the API on behalf of*, that hasn't already been refunded.**

---

*

1. Third party API calls, where you use 'subject' in your API parameters along with your username, password, and signature/certificate, are you sending API calls on behalf of the 'subject's account.
2. First party API calls are where you do not send subject, and only use your own API user,pass, and sig/cert

Comment: my transaction type is Authorization

Comment: You cannot refund an Authorization. You can void it, but no funds have been taken so there is no need to 're' fund the buyer; the buyer is already 'funded'. and just for fun, '' '' '' ''.

Comment: @khs, I would appreciate accepting my answer as the correct answer. Thanks.